# Check if the number of a textbox is greater than number entered array of textbox's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to compare value of a single text box value **"totalmarkstoall"** with multiple array of text box's **"marksscored"**, the below my java script is comparing as well on key up function.

what am unable to do is if the value of **"marksscored"**  that perticuler text box is greater then the **"totalmarkstoall"** then is shows the pop up :But it should erase the value also or should not allow to enter.

```js
function scorecompare(idval) {
    var marksscored = idval;

    var totalmarkstoall = document.getElementById("totalmarkstoall").value;
    if (parseInt(marksscored) > parseInt(totalmarkstoall))
    {
        alert("greater than Total Mrks");
    } else {

    }
}
```

```html
<input id="totalmarkstoall" type="number" style="border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;" placeholder="Enter Total Marks"></input>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="marksscored[]" id="marksscored[0]" value="" onkeyup="scorecompare(this.value);"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="marksscored[]" id="marksscored[1]" value="" onkeyup="scorecompare(this.value);"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="marksscored[]" id="marksscored[2]" value="" onkeyup="scorecompare(this.value);"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Which textbox value you need to erase?

Comment: `totalmarkstoall` or `marksscored`?

Comment: @JohnR ,  If the`marksscored` value is greater then `totalmarkstoall ` then `marksscored`  value should be erased and that pop up should show up   FYI: that particulate text box value only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do something like this you know which inputfield the value came from.

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        marksscored Array of text box's
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="marksscored[]" id="marksscored[0]" value="" onkeyup="scorecompare(this);">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="marksscored[]" id="marksscored[1]" value="" onkeyup="scorecompare(this);">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="marksscored[]" id="marksscored[2]" value="" onkeyup="scorecompare(this);">
    </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

JS:

```
function scorecompare(idval) {
   var marksscored = idval;

   var totalmarkstoall = document.getElementById("totalmarkstoall").value;
   if (parseInt(marksscored.value) > parseInt(totalmarkstoall))

   {
    alert("greater then  Total Mrks");
   //do things with inputfield marksscored
   } else {

   }
 }
```

Comment: can it replace that particulate text box value with empty if that is greater than Marksscored value

Comment: replace //do things with inputfield marksscored with marksscored.value = '';

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjRmXa

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using jquery :

1. On `keyup` calculate the sum of all text fields
2. Check if the  is greater than the Total
3. If it is the case Alert and erase the current text field `$(this).val("");`

[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m83L3prd/)

### Update:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m83L3prd/2/)

Comment: but that is not erasing the value if it is grater then totalmarks and if the entered value is text it should do nothing.

Comment: All values of text fields or the last one? please see update

Comment: this will erase the last input if the total sum is greater than supposed http://jsfiddle.net/m83L3prd/5/

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Use `keyUp` event like this way.

```js
$( ".marksscored" ).keyup(function() {
  var marksscored = $(this).val();
    var totalmarkstoall = document.getElementById("totalmarkstoall").value;
    if (parseInt(marksscored) > parseInt(totalmarkstoall))

    {
        alert("greater then  Total Mrks");
        $(this).val("");
    } else {
        // do something
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="totalmarkstoall" type="number" STYLE="    border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;" placeholder="Enter Total Marks"></input>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="marksscored" name="marksscored[]" id="marksscored[0]" value="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="marksscored" name="marksscored[]" id="marksscored[1]" value="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="marksscored" name="marksscored[]" id="marksscored[2]" value="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```